# search for substring in lucene

Tags: java, lucene

i have so many fields to get data from lucene.
one of that field is:
**NTF_com.cisco.vportal.1.TranscodingStatus**
and its value is:
**FAILED:DEPLOY_FALSE:bdecc8c3-0389-47b7-bbe5-04a2611e4be9:dms.job.transform.input.format.unsupported.error:dms.job.transform.error.type.permanent**

now i want to check to search as weather this value contain FAILED or not.

i tried with the WildcardQuery but its not working for me i put it as

```
org.apache.lucene.index.Term term=neworg.apache.lucene.index.Term("NTF_com.cisco.vportal.1.TranscodingStatus", "FAILED*");
Query wquery=new WildcardQuery(term);
```

but not getting proper result.

i just want to check that weather this field contain substring which i passed on it.

Comment: is it an analyzed field or a field of type string?

Comment: no its not analyzed ......

Comment: It has to be analyzed in order to utilize features like wildcard. For string fields you get only literal matches.

Comment: as i mentioned on question the value does not have any space between them its continues and from that i want to find FAILED.

Comment: try using WordDelimiterFilter inside an analyzed field for your terms, it should take care of extracting the word 'failed' as a separate token.

Comment: got the result which i want thax D_K....

Comment: sorry to say but i analyzed it but still not got the result.i am created new field and store failed on it and search data based on that and it is work for me....

Comment: can you post the field type definition from the schema.xml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have the content of your field searchable the first step is to make that field analyzed. That means, apply a chain of transformations, clean ups, tokenizations etc to extract searchable units (tokens).

In your case you could use the WordDelimiterFilter as one step in the analysis chain.